# "inside out" vs "ins and outs"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'inside out' and 'ins and outs'? The definitions in Cambridge English Dictionary are:

- **ins and outs** : the details or facts relating to something
- **inside out** : If you know something inside out, you know it very well

Comment: Please check the dictionary again - the definition you give for "inside out" is very wrong, and I can't find it in C.E.D. It's an adjective or adverb, not a verb.

Comment: @TypeIA, I'm sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: **Inside out** has the literal meaning of 'turned wrong side out', so if you know something inside out , you would recognise it even if you saw it the wrong way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare: 'I know the streets and lanes of my town < > I know the ins and outs of my town' ('ins and outs' is a noun phrase), and 'I know my town very well < > I know my town inside out' ('inside out' is an adverbial phrase'). If there is a difference in meaning, it is that 'know inside out' probably means a more complete knowledge than 'know the ins and outs', but the most important difference is the part of speech of each - they must be used in different ways in a sentence.